# In JavaFX 8 how can I change the background color of a cell according to the value in another cell of the same row

Tags: user-interface, javafx

I have a `TableView` in my application. Two of the columns are payment date and expiration date. In each row, I want to change the background color of individual expiration date cells based on the value of the payment date cell in the same row. My best attempt is here:

```
public class App extends Application {

    private final TableView<Bill> tableView = new TableView<>();

    private final TableColumn<Bill, Date>   tableColumnExpirationDate;
    private final TableColumn<Bill, Date>   tableColumnPaymentDate;

    public App() {
        ...
        this.tableColumnExpirationDate  = new TableColumn<>("Expires");
        this.tableColumnPaymentDate     = new TableColumn<>("Paid");

        Callback<TableColumn<Bill, Date>, TableCell<Bill, Date>>
                defaultTextFieldCellFactory = 
                TextFieldTableCell.<Bill, Date>forTableColumn(
                        new DateStringConverter());

        tableColumnExpirationDate.setCellFactory(col -> {
                TableCell<Bill, Date> cell = defaultTextFieldCellFactory.call(col);
                Bill bill = tableView.getItems().get(cell.getIndex());
                System.out.println("Bill: " + bill);
                cell.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
                return cell;
        });

        tableColumnExpirationDate.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Bill, Date>>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Bill, Date> t) {
                    // I NEED TO BE ABLE:
                    // (1) Read the 'paymentDate' field of the same row.
                    // (2) Change the color of the background of this 
                    // 'expirationDate' cell, in this row.
                    Bill bill = (Bill) t.getTableView()
                                        .getItems()
                                        .get(t.getTablePosition().getRow());

                    bill.setExpirationDate(t.getNewValue());

                    Date paymentDate = bill.getPaymentDate();
                    long now = new Date().getTime();
                    now -= now % MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY;

                    long expirationMoment = bill.getExpirationDate().getTime();

                    if (paymentDate == null) {
                        long daysLeft = (expirationMoment - now) /
                                         MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY;

                    } else {
                        long paymentMoment = paymentDate.getTime();
                        paymentMoment -= paymentMoment % MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY;

                        long days = (expirationMoment - paymentMoment) /
                                     MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY;

                        System.out.println("Days paid before: " + days);

                    }
                }
            }
        );

        tableColumnPaymentDate.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Bill, Date>>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Bill, Date> t) {
                    ((Bill) t.getTableView()
                             .getItems()
                             .get(t.getTablePosition()
                                   .getRow()))
                             .setPaymentDate(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );
    }

    ...
}
```

Everything needed to run the app is [here](https://github.com/coderodde/BillPalFXUI).

More concretely, whenever I am setting the background color of the expiration date cell, I cannot find the way for taking a look to another cell in the same row.

Comment: Can you reduce the amount of code, and make it complete so we can run it without downloading even more? (In other words, provide a [MCVE].) Surely you only need two columns here to show the actual issue, with a model class with two properties.

Comment: Done. I left only relevant parts.

Comment: Now I'm confused as to the actual requirements. What should determine the color of the cell? The `onCommitEdit` place is definitely not the place to do that, whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: For each row, the time difference between payment date and expiration date should affect the color of the expiration cell.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this is probably to use a row factory that changes the style class, or a psuedo class, on the table row. Then just set a fixed style class on the cell.

In my examples, I use `LocalDate` instead of the legacy `Date` type; you can do something like

```
PseudoClass nearlyExpired = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("nearly-expired");

table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
    TableRow<Bill> row = new TableRow<>() ;
    BooleanProperty nearlyDueProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    nearlyDueProperty.addListener((obs, wasNearlyDue, isNearlyDue) -> 
        row.pseudoClassStateChanged(nearlyExpired, isNearlyDue));
    row.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldBill, newBill) -> {
        nearlyDueProperty.unbind();
        if (newBill == null) {
            nearlyDueProperty.set(false);
        } else {

            // bind nearlyDueProperty to the time between the current Bill's
            // paymentDate and expirationDate
            // true if less than 7 days, false otherwise:

            nearlyDueProperty.bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> 
                    newBill.getExpirationDate().minusDays(7).isBefore(newBill.getPaymentDate()),
                    newBill.expirationDateProperty(), newBill.paymentDateProperty()));
        }
    });

    return row ;
});
```

and then for the column itself you just need

```
LocalDateStringConverter converter = new LocalDateStringConverter();
Callback<TableColumn<Bill, LocalDate>, TableCell<Bill, LocalDate>> defaultCellFactory = TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(converter);
expirationDateCol.setCellFactory(tc -> {
    TableCell<Bill, LocalDate> cell = defaultCellFactory.call(tc);
    cell.getStyleClass().add("expiration-cell");
    return cell ;
});
```

and finally you can attach an external style sheet with

```css
.table-row-cell:nearly-expired .expiration-cell {
    -fx-background-color: red ;
}
```

Obviously you can define the styles any way you like here.

Here is a complete example:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.util.converter.LocalDateStringConverter;

public class BillingTable extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Bill> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);

        PseudoClass nearlyExpired = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("nearly-expired");

        table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
            TableRow<Bill> row = new TableRow<>() ;
            BooleanProperty nearlyDueProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
            nearlyDueProperty.addListener((obs, wasNearlyDue, isNearlyDue) -> 
                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(nearlyExpired, isNearlyDue));
            row.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldBill, newBill) -> {
                nearlyDueProperty.unbind();
                if (newBill == null) {
                    nearlyDueProperty.set(false);
                } else {
                    nearlyDueProperty.bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> 
                            newBill.getExpirationDate().minusDays(7).isBefore(newBill.getPaymentDate()),
                            newBill.expirationDateProperty(), newBill.paymentDateProperty()));
                }
            });

            return row ;
        });


        TableColumn<Bill, LocalDate> paymentDateCol = column("Payment Date", Bill::paymentDateProperty);
        table.getColumns().add(paymentDateCol);

        LocalDateStringConverter converter = new LocalDateStringConverter();
        Callback<TableColumn<Bill, LocalDate>, TableCell<Bill, LocalDate>> 
            defaultCellFactory = TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(converter);

        paymentDateCol.setCellFactory(defaultCellFactory);

        TableColumn<Bill, LocalDate> expirationDateCol = column("Expiration Date", Bill::expirationDateProperty);
        table.getColumns().add(expirationDateCol);

        expirationDateCol.setCellFactory(tc -> {
            TableCell<Bill, LocalDate> cell = defaultCellFactory.call(tc);
            cell.getStyleClass().add("expiration-cell");
            return cell ;
        });

        Random rng = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20 ; i++) {
            LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
            LocalDate payment = now.plusDays(rng.nextInt(5));
            LocalDate expiration = payment.plusDays(rng.nextInt(14));
            table.getItems().add(new Bill(payment, expiration));
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(table);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("payment-table.css");

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S,Property<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Bill {
        private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> paymentDate = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> expirationDate = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        // other properties...

        public Bill(LocalDate paymentDate, LocalDate expirationDate) {
            setPaymentDate(paymentDate);
            setExpirationDate(expirationDate);
        }

        public final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> paymentDateProperty() {
            return this.paymentDate;
        }


        public final java.time.LocalDate getPaymentDate() {
            return this.paymentDateProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setPaymentDate(final java.time.LocalDate paymentDate) {
            this.paymentDateProperty().set(paymentDate);
        }


        public final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> expirationDateProperty() {
            return this.expirationDate;
        }


        public final java.time.LocalDate getExpirationDate() {
            return this.expirationDateProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setExpirationDate(final java.time.LocalDate expirationDate) {
            this.expirationDateProperty().set(expirationDate);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

with the stylesheet above in payment-table.css.